# Can't align vertically text inside a div which is aligned horizontally with others

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have 4 divs aligned horizontally in the same line. I'm trying to center vertically the second and third through 'vertical-align' attribute with no success.

```css
#container {
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#left {
  width:100px;
  height:45px; 
  float:left;
  background-color:red;
}

#center1 {
  width:100px;
  height:45px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
  vertical-align: center;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#center2 {
  width:100px;
  height:45px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:orange;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#right {
  width:100px;
  height:45px; 
  float:right;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="center1">Center 1</div><div id="center2">Center 2 Center 3</div>
  <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

[View in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galacticpower/yncab9ze/)

I don't want to align second and third content with 'position: relative; top: Xpx' or 'line-height: 45px;' due to second and third can have until two lines so I need to stay correctly aligned with one line and two lines.

Comment: Separate your css from the html.

Comment: edit my answer, its should work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **`display: inline-flex;`** and **`align-items: center;`** to `#center1` and `#center2`.

**Edit:** Dont forget to float them left.

---

**Example:**

```css
#container {
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#left {
  width: 100px;
  height:45px; 
  float:left;
  background-color:red;
}

#center1 {
  width: 100px;
  height:45px;
  background-color:green;
  float: left;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#center2 {
  width: 100px;
  height:45px;
  background-color:orange;
  float: left;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#right {
  width: 100px;
  height:45px; 
  float:right;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="center1">Center 1</div><div id="center2">a long line of text!</div>
  <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zeev... It's almost! Problem is, as I tried to explain in my first post, that the second center DIV can have two lines. If you change the "center2" content from "Center 2" to "Center 2 Center 3" the horizontal alignment is broken :(

Comment: just change ׳width׳ to ׳min-width׳. edit my answer :)

Comment: Sorry again, It's difficult forme to explain what I need in English... I've added the attribute 'word-break: break-word;' to the both center DIVs due to I need (only if it's needed) to have more than one line (I can't allow growing width) Is it possible. Thanks again for the ideas!

Comment: No, I've no idea :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126914/discussion-between-zeev-katz-and-ivan).

Comment: I edited your idea... Now, I only need to align horizontally (again) the orange DIV. It's almost!

Comment: Perfect, that is the behaviour I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `vertical-align:middle;` on both, the second and third element like this:

```css
#table{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  display:table-row;
}

#left{
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
  width:100px;
  line-height:45px;
  background-color:red;
}

#center1{
  width:100px;
  line-height:45px;
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:green;
  word-break: break-word;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#center2{
  width:100px;
  line-height:45px;
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:orange;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#space{
  background-color:yellow;
  display:table-cell;
}

#right{
  width:100px;
  line-height:45px;
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="container">
        <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="center1">
            Center 1
       </div>
       <div id="center2">
          Center 2 <br>Center 3
       </div>
       <div id="space">
       
       </div>
       <div id="right" style="">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated to center the text vertically and not only the element**

To position the text, use `line-height` (vertical position) which should be equal to the height of the element and `text-align:center` to center the text horizontally.

Comment: It doesn't work... The words 'Center 1' and 'Center 2' remains at the top of the DIVs (and not in the middle)

Comment: @Ivan I updated my post, I thought you only want to position the div and not the text. Should work now

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for it but problem is that I can have more than one lines so if I've got two line the second one (now) is displayed out of the DIV... I need another solution :(

Comment: @Ivan I edited the post again. What you need is a table-like layout to center the text even with dynamic heights.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use flexbox, it will make it easier to have a bar like that and easier to center thing vertically.

Have a look.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 95px;
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
.filler {
  flex: 1;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.orange {
  background: orange;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-bar">
  <div class="red box"></div>
  <div class="green box">Centered #1</div>
  <div class="orange box">Centered text number 2</div>
  <div class="box yellow filler"></div>
  <div class="blue box"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you... Another good solution a bit different from the @Zeev